# Complicated matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a (dense) matrix n x n x m and a sparse vector (scipy.sparse) 1 x m.
If we look at my dense n x n x m matrix it could be interpreted as an n x n matrix with on each position a m x 1 vector. Now I want to compute the dot product of my sparse vector with each of the m x 1 dense vectors in the n x n matrix yielding a n x n matrix with all these dot products.

One way to do this is to build a for loop to loop through the n x n matrix and then use the .dot() function of scipy.sparse to compute the dot products with each vector in the matrix. However, I'm looking for a way to perform this calculation completely in a vectorized way for efficiency. Is this possible? If not, what's the fastest way in Python to loop through my n x n matrix?

Comment: If your n*n matrix is dense then it will not matter how you loop because you need to compute the dot product with each one of n^2 elements. So a double for loop will work just fine.

Answer (score 5):

You could make the vector dense and use `dot` or `einsum`:

```
ans = arr.dot(vec.A.T)
# or
ans = numpy.einsum('ijk,k->ij', arr, vec.A.squeeze())
```

If the vector is very sparse, it's probably worthwile to first select items from the array corresponding to the nonzeros in the vector:

```
ans = arr[...,vec.nonzero()[1]].dot(vec.data)
```

For very large data it may be faster to use `tensordot` instead of `dot`, because it's more likely to call into a BLAS function:

```
ans = numpy.tensordot(arr, vec.A.T, 1)
# or, for a very sparse vec:
ans = numpy.tensordot(arr[...,vec.nonzero()[1]], vec.data, 1)
```